# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt error in Mac OS X 10.12.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm new to Python and programming. I was trying to "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" in my program but Python gives me the below error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "img_proc_canny_edge_detection.py", line 3, in 
>      import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>    File "/Users/alireza/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in 
>      _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = >pylab_setup()
>    File "/Users/alireza/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site->packages/matplotlib/backends/**init**.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
>      globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
>    File "/Users/alireza/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site->packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 6, in 
>      from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
>    File "/Users/alireza/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 203, in load_module
>      mod = mod._resolve()
>    File "/Users/alireza/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", >line 115, in _resolve
>      return _import_module(self.mod)
>    File "/Users/alireza/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", >line 82, in _import_module
>      **import**(name)
>    File >"/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/>lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in 
>      import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for >Tk
>   ImportError: No module named _tkinter

when I comment out "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" line from my program, it works perfectly.

note: I've already installed matplotlib

Comment: How did you install `python` and `matplotlib`? Did you try installing `tkinter` or changing the backend?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following lines of code and it should work in virtual environment without any issues

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use(‘TkAgg’) 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```